# Is "a row of" plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I see an example in Longman dictionary. For the word of "toolbar", it says, "a row of small pictures at the top of a computer screen that allow you to do particular things in a document". I am confused about it. The subject is "a row of small pictures" while its clause goes like "that allow you..." I think it should be like "that allows you..." Being a famous dictionary, it should be grammatical correct, even when offering a phrase instead of a complete sentence. I see in some small dictionary, an example is, "The first row alone consists of five rooms." Why Longman dictionary says that way?

Comment: There is only one row.  The row contains "small pictures that allow..."

Answer (score 6):

*A row* is singular, but *small pictures* is plural, and because it is the small pictures that are allowing you to take the action, you use "allow."

Likewise, we could expand your second sentence as follows:

> The first row alone consists of five rooms that contain tables and chairs.

*Consists* refers back to *row*, which is singular, but *contain* refers back to *rooms*, which is plural.

Comment: Quite right. After re-reading the example, I come to realize that "that allow you" modifies "small pictures". No problem occurs at all. I was confused when taking it as regarded to treat "a row of small pictures" as a whole unit. I forgot "that allow you" can only modify "small pictures".