# Is “gaggle of girls” plural or singular, or does it depend?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases

How can I tell whether constructions like “X of Ys” should be considered singular or plural, given that X is singular but Y is plural?

1. A gaggle of girls **boards** the train.
2. A gaggle of girls **board** the train.
3. The gaggle of girls **was** running to catch the train.
4. The gaggle of girls **were** running to catch the train.

Can one version be right sometimes but the other right other times?

Can both versions ever be right?

Comment: What part is it that you're questioning? I see a subject, a transitive verb, and a direct object. Are you worried that the verb needs to be plural?

Comment: Yes; I am wondering whether the verb ought to be plural. Thanks

Comment: Nope. My OED includes "a group of noisy people" in its definitions of the noun 'gaggle'.

Comment: Have you looked up *gaggle* in a good dictionary? Still have questions?

Comment: If the girls were flying instead, they would be **a** skein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "a group" singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216466/is-a-group-singular-or-plural)

Comment: See also [A group of boys is or are](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/289631/26083),  [Subject–verb agreement — two schools of thought?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69650/26083),  and [many more](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrammatical-number%5D+group).

Answer (score -2):

I would say #1 and #4 are correct, #3 is wrong, and #2 is allowable and would should they were acting individually rather than as a group. 
CMoS says:

> **5.8 Mass nouns** A mass noun (sometimes called a noncount noun) is one that denotes something uncountable, either because it is abstract {*cowardice*} {*evidence*} or because it refers to an indeterminate aggregation of people or things {*the faculty*} {*the bourgeoisie*}; the latter type is also called a collective noun. As the subject of a sentence, a mass noun usually takes a singular verb {*the litigation is varied*}. But in a collective sense, it may take either a singular or a plural verb form {*the ruling majority is unlikely to share power*} {*the majority are nonmembers*}. A singular verb emphasizes the group; a plural verb emphasizes the individual members.
>   **5.9 Mass noun followed by a prepositional phrase** Mass nouns are sometimes followed by a prepositional phrase, such as
>   *number of*  plus a plural noun. The article that precedes the mass noun signals whether the mass noun or the number of the noun in the
>   prepositional phrase controls the number of the verb. If a definite
>   article (*the*) precedes, the mass noun controls, and typically a
>   singular verb is used {the quantity of pizzas ordered this year has
>   increased}. If an indefinite article (*a* or *an*) precedes, then the
>   number of the noun in the prepositional phrase controls {a small
>   percentage of the test takers have failed the exam}

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with #3 either. It just takes the whole gaggle as a single unit, running in unison with no individual force of will or action, like one big blob of teenage girl–ness.

Comment: I don't believe 'gaggle' is a mass noun.  Rather, it's a collective noun.  https://english.ucalgary.ca/grammar/course/speech/1_1b.htm  Collective nouns are almost always considered singular in American English but can be treated as either singular or plural in British English.  http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/american-english-vs-british-english/differences-in-american-and-british-english-grammar-article/152820.article

Comment: @DanJ. +1 That's more of an answer than a mere comment.